# How to fit back-up battery into the controller board?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, low-power

I'm newbie in the field of PCB making and I have one relevant question. I have a controller on a PCB which has many resistor dividers and passive components.

I would like to know, if I want to make use of low power mode operations on the controller, how should I make the PCB?

Is it possible to make controller, battery and its power circuits (all Vdd and Vss) on one layer, and the other pins of controller on another layer?

Forgive me if I am asking stupidly.

Or please tell me how someone can crack such a problem.

By backup battery I mean a button cell 200-300 mAh, and controller is an 8-bit AVR/PIC that has low power modes.

Answer (score 1):

When I understand this correctly you want to have your MCU powered when the electricity is down. I'm not really sure what your input voltage is for your device. But I think your answer is by putting a relay which will be triggered by the main supply voltage. Connect your main supply also to the NO pin of your relay and put your battery to the NC pin. When the main supply dropped out the relay will automatically switch to its NC pin and use your battery as power supply.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned about parasitic draw through the passive components when the microcontroller is in a low power state, you'll probably want to have a separate power supply for the microcontroller.  This allows you to disable the board power supply while still keeping the microcontroller power supply enabled.  Connection-wise, you'd want to be careful that only the devices required to be on during low power are on the low-power circuit.  Many power supplies include either active-high or active-low enable inputs, so this shouldn't be too difficult to implement.